# error in showing view of a controller in asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm implementing a project with asp.net core. I have a few controller classes. I have created them by CRUD methodology. I have a controller called "ApiapplicantsController" which its related model Apiapplicant is a junction table for Api and applicant tables. In the startup file, I specified the below expressions as the URL pattern:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CSDDashboard.Data;

namespace CSDDashboard
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<CSDDashboardContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Apiapplicants}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However after ruuning the project and entering the URL, I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'CSDDashboard.Models.CSSDDashboardContext' while attempting to
>   activate 'CSDDashboard.Controllers.ApiapplicantsController'.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

I have made my connection string in appsetting file and I gave a variable name to it called CSDDashboard. The appseting file content is as follows:

```
{
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"CSDDashboardContext": "Server=MOUSA-Z2;Database=CSSDDashboard;  Trusted_Connection=True;"
},
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
}
```

}
My DBContext class name is CSSDDashboardContext. I have created all of my Controllers classes by CRUD methodology.
However, just one of my controllers use CSDDashboard variable as the context class. And when I run the project and give the URL to call the action in Vwreports, the program works correctly.

```
public class VwreportsController : Controller
  {
    private readonly CSDDashboardContext _context;         

public VwreportsController(CSDDashboardContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

But in the other Controllers CSDDashboard is unknown and the system use CSSDDashboard as the context and when I call one of those Controllers the mentioned error be shown to me. The example is provided below for one of the other Controllers that have error:

```
  public class ApisController : Controller
   {
    private readonly CSSDDashboardContext _context;

    public ApisController(CSSDDashboardContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

I appreciate if anyone help me to solve the issue.

Comment: It appears the `CSSDDashboardContext` has not been added to the service collection, so the DI container is unable to resolve it when trying to initialize the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I add that to the service collection?

Comment: The code shows that you have already added the context to the services collection

Comment: Thus, do you have any other suggestion for solving the problem?

Comment: Is the code you posted correct? I see you add the "CSDDashboardContext" to the services but not the "CSSDDashboardContext"  There is one character difference... Also you might want to try to change the order of the "ConfigureServices" content so that the Dependencies are injected before the call to "AddControllersWithViews"

Comment: Yes my code is correct. I specified the name of CSSDDashboard in my appsetting file to be CSDDashboard. I did also change order of the "ConfigureServices" content, but the issue remains. You know I have made 4 other controllers as well. for one of them there is no any error and the programs works and shows my data correctly when I set the URL pattern to be that controller. But for the other controllers when I run the program and call them through URL in browser. The mentioned error shows to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are NOT injecting the class called "CSSDDashboardContext" you are only injecting the class called "CSDDashboardContext".

So all Controllers which take CSDDashboardContext in their contructors work... And the ones that take CSSDDashboardContext do not work.

You need to inject also the CSSDDashboardContext class.

You need to add both classes like this:

```
      //this one you are already adding it according to your code
      services.AddDbContext<CSDDashboardContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));


     //Notice this is NOT the same class... Assuming this is a valid DBContext.  You need to add this class as well.
      services.AddDbContext<CSSDDashboardContext >(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDDashboardContext")));
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @hrz Please view this link which will show you how to mark answer as the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers